# How to get the last 1000 rows dynamically and sort them using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get this to sort only the last 1000 rows, dynamically.
This is the code I'm using:

```
function sort(e){
const formRespSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
let lr = formRespSheet.getLastRow()-1;
let firstRow = 2
 if (lr > 1000) {
   firstRow = lr - 1000;
 }
 Logger.log('First Row: ' + firstRow)
 Logger.log('Last Row: ' + lr)
 formRespSheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, lr, 16).sort(14);
}
```

It gives me the correct `firstRow`  and `lr`, but it also throws `The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet`, besides running forever (15 sec).

Could anyone help me find the flaw here (besides myself)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [signature](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) of getRange uses `numRows` and `numColumns`, not `lastRow` and `lastColumn`.

Because you start selecting at row 2 it tries to get a range one row beyond what the spreadsheet has.